# How to blacklist a shared library to avoid it being fetched by the loader?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld

I'm trying to force a build internal pre-processor used for built-sources to not rely on shared libraries installed in my host machine without having to uninstall them.

Although there is a `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable which forces the loader (ld-linux) to fetch the specified shared libraries before anything else, I'd like to do quite the opposite, forcing the loader **not** to fetch the specified libraries during the setup process (kind of `LD_NEVERLOAD` variable).

Is there some way to do so without breaking my entire system (aka, removing such libraries)?

PS: I've renamed my system libraries to test this specific use case, but this is definitely not an elegant way of doing so.

Comment: It seems that using `-z nodeflib` in the LDFLAGS makes the loader to skip `/usr/lib` and `/lib` directories, however, this does not work in a per-file basis, making the user to copy all relevant libraries to a separate place to get anything working.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the manual pages `ld(1)` and `ld.so(8)` you might try playing with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_RUNPATH` and options in both manuals which are related to "rpath".

Comment: @Shahbaz, nice, I didn't know there so much options to ld.so. With those options one can say where to look for alternative libraries, however none of them can instruct the loader **not** to fetch a specific library located in the default search path (`/usr/lib` in my case)