# What is LD_RUNPATH?

Tags: linux, linker, solaris

A couple of answers mention the `LD_RUNPATH` environment variable:

- [use RPATH but not RUNPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967848/use-rpath-but-not-runpath)
- [How to blacklist a shared library to avoid it being fetched by the loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260114/how-to-blacklist-a-shared-library-to-avoid-it-being-fetched-by-the-loader)

but I couldn't find any description or official reference, including in the `ld(1)` and `ld.so(8)` Linux man pages. It seems that the goal is to have a lower precedence than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, particularly useful under Solaris, where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` overrides everything.

A search on Google shows some discussions involving `LD_RUNPATH`, but nothing concrete. A search on Wikipedia is also unsuccessful. I also did some compilation/run tests with shared libraries under GNU/Linux and Solaris, but couldn't notice any effect.

So, what is this environment variable? Is there any official documentation?

Comment: Also see [What exactly does --enable-new-dtags do?](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2005-04/msg00060.html), which actually references a Sun document. The cited Sun document is available on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090609224414/http://docsun.cites.uiuc.edu/sun_docs/C/solaris_9/SUNWdev/LLM/p55.html), and it looks a lot like current documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `LD_RUNPATH`. Most likely this is a typo of `LD_RUN_PATH` or `DT_RUNPATH`.

Regarding `DT_RUNPATH`, [TechBlog](http://blog.lxgcc.net/?tag=dt_runpath) says:

> The DT_RUNPATH value is set with the linker options -rpath (or
>   LD_RUN_PATH) and the **–enable-new-dtags**.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, did not fully understand (or read enough :) ), in the ld(1) manual you have the answer:
LD_RUN_PATH is used to initialise the run path if the -rpath option is not used.

Comment: I know `LD_RUN_PATH`, but note that [it isn't taken into account by *gold*](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13764). Moreover I was asking about `LD_RUNPATH`. I was wondering whether this was a typo, but it is said that it has a lower precedence than `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is not the case of `LD_RUN_PATH` under GNU/Linux (according to tests, `LD_RUN_PATH` yields `DT_RPATH` in the binary, not `DT_RUNPATH`).

Answer (score -2):

You may find interresting informations on GNU GCC pages or on Linux documentation project.

See:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: Neither the GCC manual nor the tldp.org link you gave mentions `LD_RUNPATH`, which is my specific question.